# Mongodb query how to get createdby records or associated with records

Tags: mongodb

My user database structure is as follows

```
    {   _id:123,   fname:Name,   
        projects:[
          {projectid:123,
           createdby:123}   
        ]
    }
    {   _id:456,   fname:Name,   
        projects:[
          {projectid:789,
           createdby:456,
           teammembers:[{memberid:123},{memberid:654}]
          }
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to get the list of projects where either i am the creator or i am one of the teammembers. I have trued the following query

```
db.user.find({"$or":[{"projects.teammembers.memberid":"123"},{"projects.createdby":"123"}],{projects:1})
```

This query gives me projects where i am not a member also. 
If i put the column restriction as

> projects.$.memberid:1

mongo throws this error.

> "Positional operator does not match the query specifier."

I know by changing the structure of projects.teammembers to just array will work but for now the change process will take time.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using aggregate command.
Here's what i did

```
collection.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$projects"},
{"$match":{"$or":[{"projects.createdby":"user1"},
{"projects.teammembers.memberid":"user1"}]}},
{"$project":{"projects":1}}]
```

It gives the list of projects where i am the creator and also only those list of projects where i am a team member.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a query on a "2 levels array" that's why you get :

```
projects.$.memberid:1
```

So, you must to use the $ proection operator, for "search in each table values in their own table".

Try with

```
db.user.find({"$or":[{"projects.teammembers.$.memberid":"123"},{"projects.createdby":"123"}],{projects:1})
```

Or take a look at this doc: [Projection doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Sorry for my english

Comment: Unfortunately gives only the projects created by. the records wherein a user is a team member is not returned at all if i put the "$" operator.